# SQL Server table with dynamic columns?

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic

I am wondering how to approach this problem.

We have a profile table in our database that will be populated by a process that reads
an uploaded excel document and then dumps the columns and the data in their rows into the 
user's profile (the only thing common between all such excel spreadsheets is an email address).

Accordingly, we can't really predict what a given user's profile is going to look like. 
How do I create my profile table(s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I have to create another answer, but comment wont let me create the ascii sketch

```
----------
| user   |
----------
| id   pk|
| name   |
| .....  |
----------

----------------
| preference   |
----------------
| user_id   fk | <-- reference user.id
| header       |
| value        |
----------------
```

csv_row=`1,churk,height,11,weight,500lb,width,22,...`
OR csv_row=`1,churk,height=11,wieght=500lb,width=22......`

this will yield 1 row in user table, user.id = 1, user.name = Churk
at least 3 rows in preference. {[1,height,11],[1,weight,500lb],[1,width,22]}

So when you query the DB, all you need is

```
SELECT * FROM user JOIN preference on preference.user_id = user.id WHERE user.name = 'Churk';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have someway to process these data using a programming language, and not blinding doing mappings, the it should be pretty simple.

User_table with an ID, and some fix info such as name and what not.

Then you have a profile table that has a user_id foreign key, and key pair value, header / value

Comment: Hi Chuck, yes, that is the set-up I have right now. What I don't understand is how to account for the unpredictable column types in the excel spreadsheet when dumping to my Profile table. I am guessing this has something to do with the key/value pairs you mention (header/value)? Can you clarify a bit or provide an ASCII sketch / point me to a link? Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

How will this data be queried later? As much as I hate the practice, this may be a case of needing to store csv data in a column.

**Update:**
This might be a good fit for an [Entity Attribute Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) schema. I'm not really a fan of EAV either, but at least it's less evil than csv data in a column.

Comment: Thanks Joel. The profiles will be searched using a global search input box for attributes of their profiles, such as wearing glasses or ethnicity or whatever. I am not familiar with storing CSV data in a single column... it sounds like we'd loose our ability to search or categorize individuals based on unique attributes?

Comment: The data sounds a bit like tags, maybe? If each user has a user_id, you could load their spreadsheet data and store each piece of information against the relevant user_id.

Comment: In that case, maybe an [Entity Attribute Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) schema?